# Combining rows with NULL columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    COUNT(Table1.ID) as count_shipped,
    null as count_shipped 
from Table1  
where
    table1.saleStatus='shipped' 
    and table1.saleApproved='yes'

union

select 
    null,
    COUNT(Table1.ID) as count_pending 
from Table1  
where
    table1.saleStatus in ('Pending', 'awaiting payment', 'backorder')
```

This gives this output

```
count_shipped      count_shipped

NULL               5
 4                NULL
```

but I don't want Null I only want  4       5  in one line Can anybody help me how to do this sql server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `case` to sum up your conditions

```
select sum(case when saleStatus = 'shipped' and table1.saleApproved = 'yes' 
                then 1
                else 0 
           end) as count_shipped,
       sum(case when saleStatus in ('Pending', 'awaiting payment', 'backorder') 
                then 1 
                else 0 
           end) as count_pending 
from Table1
```